# Android icons get stretched on Samsung device

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, icons, android-drawable

I have used my custom images to develop several Action bar and tab icons using android icon set and use them as button backgrounds. They look fine on mobile handsets but when i test on Samsung galaxy tab 7", they feel stretched and blur.

I have tried making folders layout-sw600dp and layout-large but makes no difference.

One of the icons:

```
 <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/button_settings"
        android:layout_width="64dp" 
        android:layout_height="64dp"
        android:background="@drawable/settings_custom"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:contentDescription="@string/settings"/>
```

settings_custom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_action_app_sett" android:state_pressed="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_action_app_sett"/>

</selector>
```

Can anyone help me out where am I wrong? Thank you!

Comment: First of all, it seems that folders named layout-sw600dp are only added after API Level 13, secondly - are you sure that the device has a minimum width of 600 dp? (http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#support) I mean I have a Asus MemoPad 7 and I don't think it has 600dp width. 7" and 1280x800 resolution. Also, you should add the "icons" of different sizes in drawable-xhdpi, hdpi, mdpi, ldpi and so on.

Comment: You can integrated this a custom Image View to scale with any size 
you can see this exemple 
https://github.com/matabii/scale-imageview-android

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with setting android:src="@drawable/settings_custom" , for tab 7 inch you need to put images for that resolution under drawable-large-mdpi folder, please go through below link which clear more about android support for multiple screen,
http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Comment: Thank you. Making drawable-large-mdpi  folder worked.